# Change date format in R Shiny daterangeinput

Tags: r, text, shiny, lubridate

I'm building an app where users can filter data by date. I then later want to display reactive text that says "You're viewing data from start_date to end_date" in the format month, day, year. Unfortunately, shiny's daterangeInput defaults to year, month, day.

I've tried using

```
    start_date <- reactive({
        format(as.Date(input$date_filter[1]), "%d/%m/%Y")})
```

But I receive this error and the app crashes:

```
Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
  [No stack trace available]
```

Any ideas? Here's the dateRangeInput. I've also tried changing the format of the start date, but that messes up the date. Thank you!

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  dateRangeInput(
        inputId = "date_filter",
        label = "Filter by Date",
        start = "2020-01-01",
        end = NULL,
        min = "2020-01-01",
        max = NULL,
        format = "m-d-yyyy",
        startview = "month",
        weekstart = 0,
        language = "en",
        separator = " to ",
        width = NULL,
        autoclose = TRUE
      ))

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
  
})
~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "date_filter",
    label = "Filter by Date",
    start = "2020-01-01",
    end = NULL,
    min = "2020-01-01",
    max = NULL,
    format = "m-d-yyyy",
    startview = "month",
    weekstart = 0,
    language = "en",
    separator = " to ",
    width = NULL,
    autoclose = TRUE
  ), 
  
  textOutput('text')
  )

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    x <- format(input$date_filter, "%d/%m/%Y")
    sprintf("You're viewing data from %s to %s", x[1], x[2])
  })
})
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately, I'm not trying to render the text but instead print it on a slide using the officer package. When I try this format within officer's ftext argument, I get an error that I can't perform this action here:         title <- ftext(paste0("Data from ", (", input$date_filter[2], " - ", input$date_filter[2], ")"))

Comment: I haven't used `officer` package but you have a missing `"` in the code. Use `title <- ftext(paste0("Data from ", "(", input$date_filter[2], " - ", input$date_filter[2], ")"))`. Does it help or it still returns the error?

Comment: That’s just what I had originally. It output the date as “2020-01-01”. How could I get your output (e.g., 1-01-2020)that’s useable with this paste0()?

Comment: Did you try `title <- ftext(paste0("Data from (", format(input$date_filter[2], "%d/%m/%Y"), " - ", format(input$date_filter[2], "%d/%m/%Y"), ")"))` ?